# Getting invalid data from database in laravel queue

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel database queue and within queue job handler, I am getting invalid results from the database.

```php
$order->status = "confirmed";
$this->orderRepository->save($order);

logger('Order status before adding to queue: ' . $order->status);

PushToXyz::dispatch($orderId);
```

```php
class PushToXyz implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $order_id;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param int $order_id
     */
    public function __construct(int $order_id)
    {
        $this->order_id = $order_id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        app(XyzService::class)->push($this->order_id);
    }
}
```

```php
class XyzService
{
    public function push(int $order_id) {
        $order = $this->orderRepo->get($order_id);
        logger('Order status in job handler: ' . $order->status);

    }
}
```

I expect logger output to be:

`Order status before adding to queue: confirmed`

`Order status in job handler: confirmed`

But I am getting

`Order status before adding to queue: confirmed`

`Order status in job handler: new_order`

I have checked the database and status is being saved in the database correctly.

Comment: Can you post your `OrderRepository`?

Comment: can you show how you get `$order` by `$orderId`